# How to make it possible to add a lcdui Gauge to a LWUIT Container / Form?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a LWUIT Form and LWUIT Containers into the Form. I want to add a `lcdui Gauge` inside this Form , but I received an error message on my SDK.

So how to add the Gauge into the LWUIT Form / Container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't add the LCDUI components to LWUIT components. You can use [`slider`](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/07/sliding-it-back-to-my-first-post.html) instead of `Gauge`.